# Entity Framework: navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

I am working on an application where I am using EF 6. Database was developed long before and I don't have any opportunity to alter anything.

There is a `Payment` table with a `OriginatorId` column as foreign key. This foreign key could be from `Claim` table or `Invoice` table. There is another column in the `Payment` table called `OriginatorType`. If the value here is "INV" then the foreign key refers to the `Invoice` table. If the value is "CLA" then the foreign refers to the `Claim` table.

I am wondering about how I should I handle this situation in EF? I would like to have either Invoice or Claim object to be filled in when I query Payment.

Query output is just a list of payments based on filters such as `context.Payment(p => p.PaymentPostedDate >= someDate)`. Once I get this list I need to get the details of Claim and Invoice to generate reports.

Database does not map OriginatorId as foreign key. Therefore, the POCO generator does not create any reference entity. I would like to use fluent APIs to create this set up but this should have logic to parse the required entities based on OrigintorType. I know that I can write more than one queries or a proper lambda with JOIN to find the results; however, I like to handle the JOIN logic at model level. This would help me and other developers to avoid  writing complicated JOINs or many queries. This would also make Payment queries seamless.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the output you need. Any sample query we can start-with

Comment: I have updated my question to add more details. I hope that would answer your question. Thanks.